# Android wear embedded vs. companion app

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an android app with 3 apks--a mobile apk (essentially only for embedding a wear 1.x apk), the wear 1.x apk, and a wear 2.0 apk.  In reading the android guidance for packaging and distribution, they refer to companion apps and embedded apps.  It gets confusing reading the guidance.  Any help in clarifying the distinction between "embedded app" and "companion app" would be appreciated.  Simply put, what is the difference between a companion app and a embedded app?

Comment: embedded means standalone app for Android Wear 2.0, it doesn't require companion Android phone app to connect to network or to cache data. In Wear 1.0 there is only companion app option and all the network request were executed on phone app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The companion app is the APK for the phone. The embedded app is the wearable APK that is bundled with the companion app. This is only needed if you target Android Wear 1.x devices.